# Como imprimir en la tabla pocos resultados y de a poco ir incrementando? vuejs

Tags: php, javascript, vue.js

Estoy realizando una tabla que muestra todos los productos ya hechos, el problema es que al ingresar a la pagina este realiza una peticion get y se trae todos los resultados de la base de datos y los imprime, la cosa es que si son muchas la pagina pudiera colapsar y tardaria mucho, como pudiera hacer para que imprima de a poco? como los comentarios de facebook o instagram que le das a ver mas y carga 3 mas, solo que no los muestre todos de una, pero aun ingresando en el input para buscarlo lo pueda mostrar, no se si me he explicado bien xD, de todos modos aqui les dejo el codigo:

vista:

```
<table>
                <colgroup>
                    <col width="10%"/>
                    <col width="10%"/>
                    <col width="10%"/>
                    <col width="10%"/>
                </colgroup>
                <tr v-for="i in listFinishedproducts">
                    <td>{{i.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.lot}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.quantity_packed}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.pallet}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

vuejs:

```
data () {
  return { 
     listFinishedproducts: [{id: "1", room: "158", name: "colcin", lot:"2638639", quantity_packed: "15000"}
    {id: "2", room: "158", name: "colcin", lot: "2638639", quantity_packed: "15000"}
    {id: "3", room: "158", name: "colcin", lot: "2638639", quantity_packed: "15000"}
    {id: "4", room: "22", name: "frusemide", lot: "54545", quantity_packed: "1600"}
    {id: "5", room: "22", name: "frusemide", lot: "987845", quantity_packed: "1600"}
    {id: "7", room: "158", name: "zero cough", lot: "55791437", quantity_packed: "15000"}],
    filterFinishedproducts:[],
            product: '',
        },
     }
    }
        mounted() {
            this.showFinishedproducts();
        },
        methods: {
            showFinishedproducts: function() {
                axios.get("index.php?url=get_finished_products").then((response) => {
                    this.listFinishedproducts = response.data;
                    this.filterFinishedproducts = response.data;
                });
            },
            findproduct: function() {
                if (this.product === "") {
                    this.listFinishedproducts = this.filterFinishedproducts;
                }else {
                    this.listFinishedproducts = this.filterFinishedproducts.filter(products => {
                        return products.room.match(this.product.toLowerCase()) 
                        || products.name.match(this.product.toLowerCase())
                        || products.lot.match(this.product.toLowerCase())
                        || products.quantity_packed.match(this.product.toLowerCase())
                        || products.pallet.match(this.product.toLowerCase());
                    });
                }
            }
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrarme tu salida de archivo json que obtienes con axios por favor para poder trabajar en Codesandbox?

Comment: es un array de objetos que obtengo de la BD, con un simple SELECT * FROM finished_products

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar el array? si pones en la vista html  `{{ $data }}`   te muestra los array de `data: {}`

Comment: La prueba que requiero hacer es con una libreria que se llama **vue-scroll-loader o vue infinite-loading,**

Comment: esto es lo que me devuelve el response.data:, edito la pregunta para que veas

Comment: Tu consulta es la que debes variar. Un simple _SELECT * FROM ..._ es una consulta muy amplia. Te recomiendo que apliques un sistema de paginación en el lado *backend* y ajustes en el frontend para pedir y recibir los datos paginados. Saludos

Comment: me pudieras explicar mas en detalle como pudiera aplicar ese sistema de paginacion en el backend?

Comment: Para eso habría que ver si el paginado se puede hacer por medio de algún campo. Por ejemplo si el campo `id` es autonumérico, podrías general la consulta mediante dicho campo, algo como _SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id BETWEEN value1 AND value2_, donde *value1* y *value2* serían los datos de paginación que debes saber implementar y persistir entre consultas. No es tan difícil la verdad. Y es un simple ejemplo, se puede hacer de varias formas.

Comment: gracias amigo, estaba buscando por horas alguna consulta que hiciera eso en sql, seleccionar desde el 1 hasta el 5, pero todos dicen de count, con between pudiera funcionar

Answer (score 0):

Una opcion seria la siguiente donde vas mostrando registros de poco a poco donde **registrosParaMostrar** es 2 puedes reducir o aumentar la cantidad a registros a mostrar

```
<button @click="registrosParaMostrar += 2">Cargar mas</button>
```

donde +=2 son los registros a incrementar para mostrar
esta seria una opcion rapida, pero una buena practica debe de ser implementar una paginacion dentro del backend en este caso PHP hablando de si la consulta es muy pesada lo correcto es gestionarla desde el backend por medio de una paginacion
Saludos

```js
new Vue({
  el: ".vue",
  data() {
    return {
      listFinishedproducts: [
        {
          id: "1",
          room: "158",
          name: "colcin",
          lot: "2638639",
          quantity_packed: "15000"
        },
        {
          id: "2",
          room: "158",
          name: "colcin",
          lot: "2638639",
          quantity_packed: "15000"
        },
        {
          id: "3",
          room: "158",
          name: "colcin",
          lot: "2638639",
          quantity_packed: "15000"
        },
        {
          id: "4",
          room: "22",
          name: "frusemide",
          lot: "54545",
          quantity_packed: "1600"
        },
        {
          id: "5",
          room: "22",
          name: "frusemide",
          lot: "987845",
          quantity_packed: "1600"
        },
        {
          id: "7",
          room: "158",
          name: "zero cough",
          lot: "55791437",
          quantity_packed: "15000"
        },
        {
          id: "8",
          room: "158",
          name: "zero cough",
          lot: "55791437",
          quantity_packed: "15000"
        },
        {
          id: "9",
          room: "158",
          name: "zero cough",
          lot: "55791437",
          quantity_packed: "15000"
        },
        {
          id: "10",
          room: "158",
          name: "zero cough",
          lot: "55791437",
          quantity_packed: "15000"
        },           
      ],
      registrosParaMostrar: 2,
      totalRegistros: 0
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.totalRegistros = this.listFinishedproducts.length;
    console.log(this.listFinishedproducts.length);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="container vue">
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>ROOM</th>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>LOT</th>
        <th>QUANTITY PACKED</th>
      </tr>
      <tr v-if="index < listFinishedproducts.length" v-for="index in registrosParaMostrar">
        <td>{{listFinishedproducts[index].id}}</td>
        <td>{{listFinishedproducts[index].room}}</td>
        <td>{{listFinishedproducts[index].name}}</td>
        <td>{{listFinishedproducts[index].lot}}</td>
        <td>{{listFinishedproducts[index].quantity_packed}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div v-if="registrosParaMostrar < listFinishedproducts.length || listFinishedproducts.length > registrosParaMostrar">
    <button @click="registrosParaMostrar += 2">Cargar mas</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: esto es lo que quiero, pero no se como aplicar eso de paginacion en el backend, lo que se me ocurre es que haga un select con un valor inicial de las columnas a devolver, ya despues cuando le de ver mas haga esa consulta pero con el valor inicial mas la cantidad que se quiere mostrar