# Como imprimir por parte una gran cantidad de datos? vuejs

Tags: php, javascript, vue.js

Recibo un array de objetos por parte del servidor de todos los productos finalizados, el problema es que si son muchos productos, no puedo imprimirlos todos de una, como puedo hacer para que mediante de vuejs este me vaya imprimiendo por parte los productos? es decir al comienzo me imprima 3 solamente, despues abajo habra algo que diga imprimar mas, y me vuelva a imprimir 3 mas?

Comment: La palabra clave para que busques información es "paginación". La paginación la puedes implementar a mano (si buscas vas a a encontrar muchos ejemplos). También puedes usar algun plugin como `vue-paginate` para no reinventar la rueda: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-paginate

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como imprimir en la tabla pocos resultados y de a poco ir incrementando? vuejs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/365567/como-imprimir-en-la-tabla-pocos-resultados-y-de-a-poco-ir-incrementando-vuejs)